# Peculiar "disconnection" issue with ALFA AWUS036NHA (atheros 9271L)

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, network-interface, firmware

I am using: `Debian Sid (kernel 4.15.0-2-amd64)`, and I can connect flawlessly to my wifi network using my onboard `Intel 7265` and `iwlwifi` even with weak signal (e.g -80dBm).

However, I have recently got `ALFA AWUS036NHA (Atheros 9271)`, and at random moments I am not able to ping my router, despite having good signal quality (-68dBm). I have tried both `firmware-atheros` debian package and the [open source alternative](https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware/), having the same result as described below:

Normally my routing table looks like:

```
:~$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         speedport-entry 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
192.168.71.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
192.168.154.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

At random moments the routing table becomes

```
:~$ sudo route
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref       Use Iface
    default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
    192.168.71.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
        192.168.154.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

in which case pinging the gateway (192.168.1.1) and any other IP (e.g 8.8.8.8) **hangs indefinitely**. **However** *arp* works in this case, showing the rest of the connected devices, and the antenna light is blinking as expected.

The difference is in the **Gateway column** (`_gateway` vs `speedport-entry`). I can't observe any other peculiarity when it happens. It keeps the IP, netmask, etc:

```
$ ifconfig wlan1
wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.68  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:c0:ca:97:32:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4102532  bytes 3990894721 (3.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3198872  bytes 1012818336 (965.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**SOLUTION**:

The solution is either 1) to disconnect and reconnect, using Wicd (since gnome network manager's *Select Network* loads indefinitely), or 2) to wait (1-5 minutes) and it will fix automatically.

Some info:

```
$ lsmod | grep ath9k
ath9k_htc              81920  0
ath9k_common           20480  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              487424  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common
mac80211              798720  2 iwlmvm,ath9k_htc
cfg80211              720896  6 iwlmvm,ath9k_htc,iwlwifi,mac80211,ath,ath9k_common
usbcore               290816  11 ath9k_htc,usbhid,snd_usb_audio,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,snd_usbmidi_lib,btusb,uas,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci


$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: f8:ca:b8:37:ec:75
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:52 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7243000-f7243fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 59
       serial: 18:5e:0f:9f:2c:61
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-2-amd64 firmware=29.541020.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:49 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 00:c0:ca:97:32:3e
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.15.0-2-amd64 firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.1.68 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I can't locate any useful info during incidents, only previous/older logs:

```
:~$ sudo dmesg -T | grep -i ath9k
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usb 1-1: firmware: failed to load ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw (-2)
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usb 1-1: Direct firmware load for ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw failed with error -2
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:44 2018] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51008
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:44 2018] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:44 2018] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:44 2018] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[Fri Apr 13 00:38:49 2018] usb 1-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51008
[Fri Apr 13 00:38:49 2018] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
```

The only relevant errors I have found (last three lines) ~ again these logs are previous, and not repeating at the "disconnections" that I have looked into.

```
:~$ sudo dmesg -T | grep -i error
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:38 2018] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:39 2018] i801_smbus: probe of 0000:00:1f.3 failed with error -16
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:42 2018] EXT4-fs (sdb3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:42 2018] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[Thu Apr 12 20:57:43 2018] usb 1-1: Direct firmware load for ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw failed with error -2
[Fri Apr 13 00:38:48 2018] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

Any ideas how could I debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problems with this adapter and after debugging the drivers for a long time, I did not find the problem.  Then I have noticed that the same problems also exists under Windows, which were installed on the same machine (with dual boot). This would make driver problems a hell of a coincidence so I started suspecting, that the problem is with this WiFi adapter's hardware or with the USB port that serves it. Therefore, I returned the old and reordered a new `ALFA AWUS036NHA` WiFi adapter and installed a new PCIe card with a pair of new USB ports.

To my surprise the problems persisted ON BOTH operating systems!

Remembering, that the LED indicator light of this WiFi adapter sometimes freezes ( mostly in the OFF state ), I started suspecting that the MCU inside this WiFi adapter becomes hung or reset due to some power supply issues, so I plugged an `inline USB power monitor` into the Mini-B USB socket of the WiFi adapter, set it to `MAX Hold display` and discovered, that this adapter draws **more** current than the maximum allowed by the USB standard ( which is 500mA ) by intermittently drawing up to 830mA on stock settings (and up to 910mA with the [increased TX power hack](https://miloserdov.org/?p=337) ).

After constructing my own 3meter long USB cable out of a 90Ω impedance shielded twisted pair cable ( S/STP with 16AWG conductors ) with one USB Mini-B jack at one end of this cable and two paralleled USB Type-A jacks at the other end of this cable for drawing the supply current from 2 host USB sockets at the same time (but the data only form one USB socket!), all of the random disconnection problems, hangs and lockup problems have disappeared.